# Argo CronWorkflow is submitted immediately after resume

Tags: workflow, argo, argo-cron-workflows

After resuming an Argo CronWorkflow, this workflow is submitted immediately even though the schedule is not due to run until a few hours later. Resuming the Argo CronWorkflow does not submit it immediately.

I tried to change the Argo CronWorkflow configuration without any success.

How can I delay submitting a CronWorkflow after resuming?

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: I meant adding it as an answer, i.e. use the "Post Your Answer" button. Comments are ephemeral and likely to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED After deleting the Argo CronWorkflow in the UI and deploying it again with Helm, the problem disappeared. Thanks and sorry @Adriaan